# Unique subspace stable under upper triangular matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, induction

$F$ is a field and $B$ is the subgroup of $GL_n(F)$ consisting of upper triangular matrices.

Let $e_0,e_1,\cdots,e_{n-1}$ be a basis with respect to which $B$ is upper-triangular, and write
$$V_i=\langle e_j:j\geq i\rangle$$

Prove that:

> $V_{n-i}$ is the unique subspace $W$ of dimension $i$ such that $W B \subseteq W$.

---

**Background:** I was looking for a solution without using the Bruhat decompositon of the following problem:

> If $B$ is the subgroup of ${\rm GL}(n,F)$ consisting of upper triangular matrices then normalizer of $B$ in ${\rm GL}(n,F)$ is $B$ itself.

And I saw an answer on mathstack: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2087257/1033621
prove that statement using the lemma above. However I am confused by the proof of the lemma saying that **pass to $V/V_{n-1}$ and use induction**. Why vector space $V_{n-1}$ is necessarily in $V$, which satisfies that $VB\subseteq V$  and how can the induction hypothesis be applied to the quotient space?

Any help would be appreciated!